# Netgear router missing wireless configuration menu link

Tags: wireless-router, firmware

I have a Netgear WiFi router DG834G v3. On it it says it's a WiFi, ADSL 2+ modem, switch, etc. There is an antenna on the back and a WiFi indicator on the front. However, when I connect to it via the web interface, the wireless setup link is missing from the menu. The top label indicates it is a DG834 (without G). I have received it from a friend and was really looking forward to using it but I really need the WiFi part.

I looked on Netgear's site as I thought someone must have uploaded the wrong firmware for the device sometime - so I upgraded to the latest firmware, but it still says it's NOT a 'G' device and the wireless menu is nowhere to be found.

I'd appreciate a push in the right direction as to what I could do. Is it possible that the WiFi chip is broken or something and the device does not detect it and the firmware reverts the device to a different version?

Answer (score 1):

If it has an antenna, then it must have wireless capability.

Look on the back or underside of the device for a model number.  Perhaps your friend was trying to put OpenWRT on it and flashed it back w/ the wrong firmware.  If the model # on the hardware says DG834G, I would flash it with [the latest firmware](http://kb.netgear.com/app/products/model/a_id/2325).

Comment: I have already flashed it with that firmware several times with no success.

Comment: I find it odd that Netgear would use the same firmware for two different models of a device. This helps the device confuse things I guess ... should something malfunction

Comment: It's fairly likely that they would choose to use the same base chipset for similar wired/wireless devices and thus the same base firmware (less development/testing).

Comment: When you say "no success", do you mean it completed the flash and rebooted itself?  Or did it reject the file?

Answer (score 0):

According to this article on the Netgear site, containing the DG834 [specifications](http://www.netgear.com/Products/RoutersandGateways/WiredRouters/DG834.aspx), this model does:

> Four products in one, this versatile
>   modem router combines an ADSL modem,
>   router, four-port 10/100 LAN switch,
>   and SPI Double Firewall

Unfortunately, wireless is not one of its functions. It's only an ADSL modem and router.

As you rightly suspected, the `DG834G` model is the one that does wireless.

Comment: I have already specified the device IS a DG834G v3 and it should have wi-fi.

Comment: Doesn't look like the firmware agrees with you. I don't know how you got that router, but if it's still under guarantee then use it. Otherwise, the only thing to do is open it up and clean inside and press well on all chips in the hope of fixing a bad contact. If that doesn't help, then a new router is in order.

Comment: Yeah, it's not under warranty, I got it in a bag along with other routers from a friend. I was hoping at least ONE of them would work. Maybe in the 'boot' process, it can't find some chip, like you said, and it thinks it's a different model. I will try opening it and checking things out. Thanks